# Not able to make sprite interaction to work

Tags: javascript, html, interaction, pixi.js

I'm trying to build a simple game menu, containing some clickable sprites, which will be used as buttons to navigate around the menu.

*( I'm using the latest pixi.js (v4.3.5) )*

**Structure of my app:**

- loader.module ( makes use of the pixi.loaders.Loader )
- events.module (basic event sub/pub module)
- base.view
- menu.view ( extends base.view )
- game.main

**How it all works now ?**

Both all resources and ui elements have to be explicitly defined, before initializing the view.

so in the menu.view, the follwoing attributes have to be defined.

```
    this.resources = [
      { name: 'start', src: 'img/start.png'},
      { name: 'start2', src: 'img/start2.png'}
    ];

   this.ui = [{
        name: 'start', /// resource name
        type: 'img',
        pos: { x: 0, y: 0 }
   }];
```

Now I only need to call `view.init()` to get it all loaded and drawn. On the visual side, evrything works perfectly, however the 'start' sprite (which has it's `interactive` and `buttonMode` set to `true`) is not reacting to any mouse events.

The below method is responsible for getting the required resource and returning a new sprite. It also enables the actual interaction functionality as part of this process. But the test function is never triggered for some reason.

```
__getSpriteObject( element ){
        let sprite = new PIXI.Sprite( this.loader.loader.resources[ element.name ].texture );
        sprite.x = element.pos.x;
        sprite.y = element.pos.y;

        sprite.interactive = true;
        sprite.buttonMode = true;
        console.log( sprite )

        sprite.on('pointerdown', function(){
            console.log("what")
        })
        return sprite;
    }
```

If the above info isn't sufficient , here is also a working [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/CwO4ypKaSkyQWSqAQM1E?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

I answered this here: http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/28474-not-able-to-make-sprite-interaction-to-work/?do=findComment&comment=163647 in any case anyone else is curious